# Flyway did not create tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I have been trying to create a web application using spring boot and flyway. The build tool is Gradle. However, when I try to run the program Flyway creates just one table named flyway_schema_hystory but doesn’t create a table from SQL script. Script `V1__Create_all_tables.sql` is on correct package `src/main/resources/db/migration`. Dependency in `build.gradle` was added, flyway properties were added in `app.properties` as well.
Spring boot runs without errors.

`build.gradle` dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.4.2'

    annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.0.0.Alpha5')

    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.18'

    compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '7.5.3'
}
```

`app.properties`

```
#Databse
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

#Flyway
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
spring.flyway.check-location=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.enabled=true
```

Example of sql script for creating a table (I’m using postgresql):

```
create table my_table (
                       id serial not null constraint cover_pkey primary key,
                       name varchar(30) not null ,
                       is_deleted boolean not null
);
```

[flyway_schema_hystory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMFTZ.png)

What's can be a problem?

Comment: I'm using the same configuration (postgres, gradle, springboot, flyway) and have a similar properties file. One of the differences is that my baselineOnMigration is written like this baseline-on-migrate. Can you try changing that? @OlSi

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me. But thanks anyway @dextertron_

Comment: Try changing the name, maybe v1 is reserved for flyway initial migration. Try something like V1_1__Create_all_tables.sql

Comment: This is my whole configuration for db (text formatting will be bad here) ->
spring:
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        database: postgresql
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: validate
            use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
    datasource:
        platform: postgres
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev_db
        username: dev_user
        password: dev_pass
    flyway:
        enabled: true
        locations: classpath:db/migrations
        baseline-on-migrate: true

Comment: Also, can you confirm that you can see the flyway library in your project's external libraries?

Comment: Rename to V1_1__Create_all_tables.sql worked, tables added to db. Thanks a lot! @dextertron_

Comment: I will write that as an answer, and you can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the name, I think v1 is reserved for the flyway's initial migration. Try something like V1_1__create_all_tables.sql

Answer (score 0):

Here, where is the credntial for flyway, if not define then need to add below connection config in application.properties.

```
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.flyway.user=postgres
spring.flyway.password=postgres
```

Make sure, your database running on right port.